# WordPress plugin PHP code not inserting data into database - what's the problem?

Tags: php, database, wordpress, plugins, insert

I work with XYZ PHP Code WordPress plugin. Why this code dont't work?
Table structure: id (int, AI), name (varchar), mail (varchar), message(varchar), date (datetime)

```
if(isset($_POST['add']) && $_POST['name'] && $_POST['mail'] && $_POST['message'])
                {
                    global $wpdb;

                    $name= $_POST['name'];
                    $mail= $_POST['mail'];
                    $message= $_POST['message'];
                    $date= current_time('mysql'); 
                
                    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mytable';
                    
                    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'mail' => $mail,
                        'message' => $message,
                        'date'=> $date));
                        
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking if `$_POST['add']` has been set, and are allowing for `$_POST['name']`, `$_POST['mail']` and `$_POST['message']` to be nullable.

Ensure your table schema allows for these fields to be null. If it doesn't allow null values, wrap these variables in `isset()`.

`isset($variable)` determines if a variable is declared and is different than null.

To understand more why this code isn't executing correctly, you should take a look at the error logs.